# Angular Inject and compile HTML with Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with a legacy MVC application, and I want to implement some Angular into one of the views.

After the initial struggle of getting Angular to `$compile` the new DOM, I'm left with an error that i can't seem to overcome.

The way it works (and something I cannot change) is that jQuery loads the specific view/layer markup, and when its in the DOM, I do the following:

```
// Compiles the DOM into the Angular application
if ($layer.hasClass('angular-view')) {
    angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        $compile($layer)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    });
}
```

This allows me to see the evaluated value (`{{2+2}}`) on the rendered page, which is great, however, when I try to compile a controller into the markup, I get the following error:

> Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined

This is the markup I'm injecting into the application:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <span>{{2+2}} - {{name}}</span>
</div>
```

Here's how I'm declaring the app module:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Terry Nutkins";
    });
```

I'm initialising the application in the "main" DOM like this:

```
<body ng-app>
    <!-- Content -->
</body>
```

(I've also tried ng-app="app")

Any thoughts?

---

I should also add that when I query the module in the debug console, I can see the controller sitting there, ready to go.

```
angular.module('app')._invokeQueue[0][2][0]
"MyController"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the cause of the issue - and I hope someone else finds this useful.

When I inject and compile the DOM, I need to specify WHICH injector I want to use. In my case, I needed to add 'app' to the array of the `angular.injector` call

```
// Compiles the DOM into the Angular application
if ($layer.hasClass('angular-view')) {
    angular.injector(['ng', 'app']).invoke(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        $compile($layer)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    });
}
```